# Connecting GCC compiler to Web Server

Tags: php

I have created a website.I want people to submit the source-code of given Problem statement
on the website.I want immediate response to the code...i.e..showing compile-time error or 
runtime error,if any.This all should be done immediately with the submission of code.The fully correct code will be accepted.
How to connect GCC to the web-server????

Comment: That's great. What have you tried?

Comment: wouldn't allowing people to compile arbitrary code on your server be somewhat of a security risk?

Comment: i have just work on the site..but how to do this job  i.e. connecting gcc to server.....i still don't have any idea...my site(database) is accepting everyone's code.. :(

Comment: once this solution is implemented, your server will last for a maximum of 5.5 seconds..

Comment: Raidenance....then what will you say about a website.. www.codechef.com

Comment: Jay....actually i am doing this for my college technicalfestival...so i don't need arbitrary code to be compiled on my server...actually my ques. are fixed....ofcourse arbitrary code is not the right answer so will not be accepted....i want to make something like this...

Comment: @abhishek what you just said turned this question into an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184612/any-framework-to-build-a-code-checking-websitelike-spoj

Comment: @abhishek: There are enough sites out there like codegolf.com, projecteuler.net, topcoder et al. But the architecture needed to have a fail-safe controlled sandbox environment to compile/run user submitted code that does not harm the server is not as simple as asking "how to connect GCC to web server".. Just letting you know that you will need to go really really deeper than that to have a robust solution for what you need.

Comment: @abhishek even if you don't care what Raidenace said, you should because if you don't, your `gcc connected to web` will fail as soon as the not so good programmer but good techie crashes your contest!

Answer (score 1):

You are introducing some incredible security vulnerabilities exposing this functionality to the internet. However, try this:

```
exec('gcc test.c', $output, $return); 

var_dump($output); 
var_dump($return);
```